# create and mount partition on running VM Linux system

Tags: linux, partitioning, virtual-machine

I have an Ubuntu 12.04 machine running as a VM and I would like to create a 'data' directory with the unallocated space left on `/dev/sda`. I managed to create a `/dev/sda3` partition on the available space, but I cannot see any way of defining a mount point for the new space. Is it possible to do this on a running system?

Once I have created the partition with gparted, the system looks like this:

[image]

But if I query it from a terminal, `/dev/sda3` won't show up:

```
df -ah
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1       7.4G  6.1G  963M  87% /
proc               0     0     0    - /proc
sysfs              0     0     0    - /sys
none               0     0     0    - /sys/fs/fuse/connections
none               0     0     0    - /sys/kernel/debug
none               0     0     0    - /sys/kernel/security
udev            7.7G  4.0K  7.7G   1% /dev
devpts             0     0     0    - /dev/pts
tmpfs           3.1G  404K  3.1G   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            7.8G   72K  7.8G   1% /run/shm
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is possible. To mount it on the directory `/foo` run:

```
sudo mount /dev/sda3 /foo
```

To make this permanent you need to edit `/etc/fstab` and ad a line like this:

```
/dev/sda3   /foo    ext3    defaults    0   0
```

This assumes that the partition has an ext3 filesystem. If not, change `ext3` to `ext4` or `ntfs` or whatever. Similarly, to specify the filesystem on the command line do:

```
sudo mount -t ext3 /dev/sda3 /foo
```

Comment: The issue is that `/dev/sda3` doesn't show up in the system.

Comment: @130490868091234,  It won't show up in `df` unless it's mounted. Try the command I gave and then run `df` again. To see all partitions (mounted or not) run `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda`.